# Target display mode on mid 2011 iMac

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-16.04, imac, thunderbolt

I have an old 21.5" iMac (mid 2011) sitting around that's running OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)¹. It is [listed by apple](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh30822/mac) as one of the machines supporting Target Display Mode through Thunderbolt.

I also have a Lenovo Thinkpad T470s with one Thunderbolt 3 port, running on a dual boot with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10. I hooked up an official [Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 adapter](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MMEL2AM/A/thunderbolt-3-usb-c-to-thunderbolt-2-adapter) and an official [Thunderbolt cable](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD861LL/A/apple-thunderbolt-cable-20-m) from my Thinkpad to my iMac.

> **Goal.** I would like to use my iMac as a display for my Thinkpad (under Ubuntu), for example using Target Display Mode.

Although this is not officially supported, people [have reported being able to make things like this work](https://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/akrish11//2017/09/11/using-the-imac-27-late-2015-as-an-external-monitor.html). So far I've been unsuccessful, and I make the following observations:

1. When I press Cmd + F2 on iMac, nothing happens (not even a short black screen, as is reported by other users).
2. When I try Target *Disk* Mode² instead of Target Display Mode, the iMac shows a screen showing both a Firewire and a Thunderbolt logo, indicating that both options are supported (I have both ports).
3. Both Windows and Ubuntu seem to acknowledge that there is a Thunderbolt 3 port on my Thinkpad, but neither seem to be aware of my iMac sitting on the other end.

So some specific questions are:

1. Does this iMac indeed support Target Display Mode through Thunderbolt on OS X 10.7.5?
2. Is there any problem using a Thunderbolt 3 to Thunderbolt 2 converter on a Thunderbolt 1 machine?
3. Do I need to install any additional Thunderbolt 3 drivers on Windows or Ubuntu?
4. How can I check whether *any* connection at all between the devices is established?

Failing all that,

5. What are other options for using my iMac screen with my Ubuntu machine? For example, what is the easiest way to set up Screen Sharing through Ethernet across operating systems, e.g. using X11 or VNC? Bonus points for open source.

---

¹This computer is still used for specific (offline) tasks, and upgrading the OS is currently not an option.

²I did not explore the Target *Disk* Mode option further (for diagnostics only), because it leads into new problems, e.g. file system compatibility.

Comment: Only the 27" iMacs were ever capable of Target Display Mode. I'd investigate some version of VNC, which Macs can use natively.

Comment: @Tetsujin: thanks for your comment. However, many official websites explicitly list 21.5" iMacs as supporting Target Display Mode. See for example [this (old) Apple support page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592).

Comment: That said, I am starting to get the feeling that you're right that this is not going to work on my machine...

Comment: Ah, you're right, it was only the early ones limited to 27. My bad.

Comment: Have you ever been able to figure this out?

Comment: @Alexander unfortunately, no. Still no clue why not. (I could try again now that I have different hardware and a different OS, but I suspect that this precise iMac is just not going to support it.)